# How do you programmatically add table rows at specified points in a table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Here's a jsFiddle with some example code: http://jsfiddle.net/x9faq/

I have a table which contains a number of rows containing a 'group' and an 'item' column. The table is populated by data from a database and rows are grouped by 'group'.

There is also a way for users to dynamically add rows to the table but currently the new rows are immediately added onto the end like so:

```
$('.Table > tbody:last').one().append(tr);
```

What I would rather happen is that the row is slotted in at the bottom of its relevant group. In the actual script the 'categoryTitle' is generated dynamically but for the example I've hardcoded it as 'Drugs'. The closest I have got to being able to slot in a new row while maintaining the 'Group' grouping is this:

```
$('.Table tr>td:contains("' + categoryTitle + '")').one().last().after(tr);
```

If you click the 'add row' button in the example it will add a row after the last 'Drugs' group item but it will literally add it after the table cell containing 'Drugs' which is not quite what I want.

My other issue with this is that the table may not always contain data there already, in which case my code fails because it can't find any relevant table column. How do I control this conditionally so that if the table is empty or no relevant 'Group' row already exists it just adds a row to the end of the table, otherwise it slots the new row in after the last matching 'Group' row?

Comment: I don't think [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) does what you think it does.

Comment: @Juhana Very possibly so, though your answer was not very helpful in correcting my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`one` is used to attach an event handler for a single event instance, and is not relevant to your example.

You instead need to remove that and use `parent()` to get back up to the `tr` element and insert the new row `after` that. Try this:

```
var $table = $('.Table');
var $lastRow =  $('tr > td:contains("' + categoryTitle + '")', $table).last().parent();
if ($lastRow.length) {
    $lastRow.after(tr);
}
else {
    $table.append(tr);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9faq/2/)

Comment: This works fantastically, thank you. However this still requires a relevant row to exist for it to work. How would I get this to default to simply adding the row to the end of the table in case of an empty table or no relevant 'group' row already existing?

Comment: @Roy You need to check if any rows exist using `length`, and if not append to the `table` itself. See my update

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much for your help Rory!